# Где нужно хранить выданный ключ api?

Tags: php, ajax, api

Есть сервис, который предоставляет api для разработчиков.
Я получил этот код с целью сделать свой сервис.
Вся суть моего сервиса сводится к тому, что этот ключ используется для отправки запросов на сервер ресурса, после чего поступает ответ в виде json, парсится и отображается в виде инфы.

Просто проблема в том, что мне сервер не нужен-то, всё можно сделать аяксовыми запросами, никаких БД не будет, по сути-то планируется одностраничный сайт.
Но api-ключ хранить нужно и никому он не должен попасть в руки.

Я думал-думал и додумался лишь до того, что нужно всё-таки приобретать хостинг для хранения этого ключа в каком-нибудь php скрипте, а в каждом аякс запросе делать запрос на получения этого ключа. Защититься можно тем, что запросы на получение api-ключа этот скрипт будет принимать лишь от моего сервиса.
Но разумно ли это вообще?... Скорее всего есть более разумное решение всему этому?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем я не прав и как реализовать идею получше.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61636/discussion-on-question-by-vostoksisters------api).

Comment: Хороший же вопрос, почему так мало ответов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое разумное решение - все-таки использовать некий хостинг или что-либо подобное для хранения секьюрной информации, это как бы вытекает из самого понимания того, что она секьюрная. Но если нет желания выбирать и оплачивать какой-либо платный хостинг, можете попробовать найти бесплатные варианты. Вопрос в том, насколько они будут защищенными.

Comment: Вопрос больше был не в том, использовать его или нет... Я глупо его задал, признаюсь, тут определенно стоит использовать хостинг. Вопрос был в том, как защитить этот ключ... Я такого никогда раньше не делал и не знаю, как лучше.

Comment: Ключ стоит защищать именно что хранением его в скрипте у себя на хостинге, ничего более не требуется, кроме проверки, откуда приходит запрос к этому скрипту.